# Совпадение имен переменных ajax и yandex maps api

Tags: jquery, ajax, yandex-maps-api

Есть код, в ajax при ошибке выполняется функция error, посредством геокодинга получаю координаты дома, если ошибка api выдает объект json

```
{"error":{"status":"400","message":"missing geocode parameter"}}
```

в котором есть объект error, то есть не могу обратиться к объекту из-за совпадения имен.

```
$.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: dataToSend,

                    success: function (data) {
                        //text
                    },

                    error: function (data){
                        console.log(data.error);

                    }

                });
```

Вроде легкое, но никак не придумаю, как быть?
Использовать $.ajaxError ?

Comment: оформил тут весь свой код http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLbXmN Нажимаем кнопку reset чтобы пустить пустую строку для формирования ошибки и затем кнопку  get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> не могу обратиться к объекту из-за совпадения имен

Дело не в этом. Из http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

> **error**
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

так что `data` в Вашем `error: function (data){` `data` - это `jqXHR`, а не JSON.

Два варианта:

или вызывается `success`, и Вам надо проверять `data.error` там:

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data.error) {
    console.log(data.error);
  }
},
```

или вызывается `error` и тогда:

```
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown){
  var data = $.parseJSON(errorThrown);
  console.log(data.error);
}
```

**Update**

Вот правильный вариант, который соответствует ответу на запрос `jqXHR.responseText = "{'error':{'status':'400','message':'missing geocode parameter'}}"`:

```
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log(request.responseText);
  var data = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
  // или
  var data = request.responseJSON;
  console.log(data.error.message);
}
```

Comment: Видимо неправильно применил терминологию. Дело в том, что к data я обращаюсь как к объекту без $.parseJSON и все работает, вот так success: function (data) {
                        var coord = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.Point.pos; Попробовал ваш первый вариант, success даже не срабатывает вообще. Второй ваш вариант выдает ошибку SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );

Comment: оформил тут http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLbXmN

Comment: добавьте в `error:` первой строчкой `console.log(jqXHR.responseText)`. Что выводится в консоль?

Comment: {"error":{"status":"400","message":"missing geocode parameter"}}

Comment: да, спасибо, разобрался, впрочем работает и данная конструкция без $.parseJSON - error: function (data){
                        console.log(data.responseJSON.error.message);
                    }

Comment: @Jean-Claude - Заклинаю Вас - не называйте первый параметр обработчика `error` - `data`! "Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг!" Александр Дюма